# Designdata in winrt when using reactiveui

Tags: winrt-xaml, reactiveui

I am trying to build an WinRT app with reactive ui and am getting the following error when constructing designdata:

The type initializer for 'ReactiveUI.RxApp' threw an exception
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: dispatcher

my design data looks like this:

```
<FormViewModel xmlns="using:sRM.Controls.ViewModels">
    <FormViewModel.Form>
       <Form xmlns="using:sRM.Models.Forms" Name="Design form"/>
    </FormViewModel.Form>
 </FormViewModel>
```

for my viewmodel

```
public class FormViewModel : ReactiveViewModel, IFormViewModel
{
    private readonly IFormsService _formsService;
    //private AccountViewModel _Data;
    private Form _Form;

    public FormViewModel() 
    {

    }
 ..
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [should be fixed](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/commit/be5c861b8b2c29dd98ec5bf918eff77e618d9ec5) in the latest version that will be released soon!

**Update:** This is now released in ReactiveUI 4.3.0

Comment: Great! i will try this asap